# How do I identify predatory conferences? How do I find the 'best' conferences?

Tags: conference

Title. I have an inkling this may be a predatory conference, but I'm wondering if there's a way to be absolutely certain: https://www.coreconferences.com/icalh2022/

Additionally: how does one find the best conferences in a particular field? Is it just a 'if you know, you know' sort of thing? As an undergrad, I feel a bit lost.

Comment: We do not answer questions about individual conferences, journals, etc. You *should* feel lost as an undergraduate, you're just starting! You really need an advisor/mentor at your stage, and will continue to need one through graduate school and beyond.

Comment: It can be useful to search for "[organizer] scam" or variants thereof. The first hit I got is [this](https://e-nns.org/blog/2021/09/15/warning-about-fake-conferences-on-artificial-neural-networks-in-2020/), which certainly suggests the organization is predatory.

Comment: "As an undergrad, I feel a bit lost." rightly so. It is a long way from "understanding the textbooks on a certain subject" to "understanding new development of a certain subject". Reputable conferences are the ones that provide a "showcase" and a discussion venue for reputable research. 
Researchers are quite conservative, so they tend to stick in groups (gangs, sometimes): join your national association of professionals on a certain subject, it will help.